# Extend polyline and handle mouse event

Tags: google-maps-api-3, event-handling, mouseevent, polyline, extending

I write JS app where I draw a lot of polylines using array of points, but in avery point I have some additional properties in this point (GPS data, speed etc).

I want to show these additional props onmouseover or onmouseclick event.

I have two ways:

1. use the standard polylines and event handler. But in this case I can't to determine additional properties for start point of this polyline cause I can't to save these props in polyline properties. There is one solution - save in array additional properties and try to find them by LatLng of first point of the polyline, but it's too slow I guess..
2. extend polyline and save additional properties in new Object, but I can't to extend mouse events :(

To extend polyline I use this code:

```
function myPolyline(prop, opts){
    this.prop = prop;
    this.Polyline = new google.maps.Polyline(opts);
}

myPolyline.prototype.setMap = function(map) {
    return this.Polyline.setMap(map);
}

myPolyline.prototype.getPath = function() {
    return this.Polyline.getPath();
}

myPolyline.prototype.addListener= function(prop) {
    return this.Polyline.addListener();
} 

myPolyline.prototype.getProp= function() {
    return this.prop;
}

myPolyline.prototype.setProp= function(prop) {
    return this.prop = prop;
}
```

and create new object in for loop (i - index of current point in array of points) like that:

```
var polyline_opts   = {
    path: line_points,
    strokeColor: color,
    geodesic: true,
    strokeOpacity: 0.5,
    strokeWeight: 4,
    icons: [
        {
        icon:   lineSymbol,
        offset: '25px',
        repeat: '50px'
        }
    ],              
    map: map
};

var add_prop    = {
    id:  i,
    device_id: device_id
};

... 

devices_properties[device_id].tracks[(i-1)] = new myPolyline(add_prop, polyline_opts);
```

Where:

- line_points - array of points (just two points),
- i - current point index
- devices_properties[device_id].tracks - array of extended polylines (with add properties) by my device_id index

After that I set event handler like that:

```
var tmp = devices_properties[device_id].tracks[(i-1)];
google.maps.event.addListener(tmp.Polyline, 'click', function(e) {
...
console.log(tmp.prop.id);
...
}
```

But in this case I always get the same id in console..

When I use

```
google.maps.event.addListener(devices_properties[device_id].tracks[(i-1)].Polyline, 'click', function(e) {
...
console.log(???); // How to get parent of polyline fired the event?
...
}
```

I don't know how to get parent of polyline fired the event?

Comment: I answer my own question - It's done, I've just have some troubles with using "for" instead "$.each" :)

Answer (score 1):

I answer my own question - It's done, I've just have some troubles with using "for" instead "$.each" :)

Before I use:

```
for ( i = 1; i < devices_properties[device_id].history_points.length; i++ ) {
    ...
    create myPolyline
    ...
}
```

and it's doesn't work - created one event handle.

After:

```
$.each(devices_properties[device_id].history_points, function(i, tmp){
    ...
    create myPolyline ()
    ...
}
```

and it works - create a lot of event handlers.

To handle event I use this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(c_polyline.Polyline, 'mouseover', function(e) {
    var prop = c_polyline.getProp();
    ...
    console.log(prop.id, prop.device_id);
}
```

Comment: Did you ever figure out why the for loop implementation doesn't work? I'm trying to avoid jQuery, if possible, since it is not needed elsewhere in my app.